# Install MongoDB shell client without server

Tags: 18.04, package-management, mongodb

Where is the shell client for MongoDB, I found a number of packages related to MongoDB in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS but can't seem to find information where exactly is this client and what I should install.

I know that if I install the MongoDB package the shell will be included but I don't need the server and other stuff because I have Atlas (cloud db server).

Here are the links I found on the internet:

- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/database/mongodb-clients
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/mongo-tools

Does it make sense going trough all the trouble above and should I simply install the MongoDB package?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**IMPORTANT**: The legacy `mongo` shell was deprecated in the MongoDB 5.0 release and removed in the 6.0 release packages. The modern replacement is the [MongoDB Shell (`mongosh`)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/install/#procedure) which is a more fully featured JavaScript and Node.js REPL environment that is also compatible with a broader range of MongoDB server versions. For example, as of Feb 2024 `mongosh` was supporting MongoDB Server v4.2 and greater.

### (original answer from March 2019 below)

If you just want the `mongo` shell, you could install the `mongodb-clients` package mentioned in your question. However, note that this includes an older shell version (3.6.3).

The official MongoDB packages are updated with each minor release and you should ideally install a shell version matching your MongoDB server's major version (3.6, 4.0). Significant mismatches in shell versus server versions can result in some subtle errors as well as missing or outdated helpers. For example, the MongoDB 3.6.x shell doesn't have helpers for transactions (which were added in 4.0).

The MongoDB documentation includes information on [Installing the official packages on Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-mongodb-community-edition-using-deb-packages). There is a `mongodb-org-shell` package which only includes the MongoDB shell, and you may also want to install `mongodb-org-tools` for other command-line tools (`mongodump`, `mongorestore`, ...).

It would be best to follow the instructions in the MongoDB documentation as some details may change in future (such as the signing key), but the general steps to follow for MongoDB 4.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) are:

1. Import the public key used to sign packages from MongoDB, Inc

   ```
    sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4
   ```
2. Create a package list file for MongoDB

   ```
    echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list
   ```
3. Update your local package database

   ```
    sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Install the desired MongoDB package(s)

   ```
    sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org-shell
   ```

*NOTE*: The legacy `mongo` shell was deprecated in the MongoDB 5.0 release and removed in the 6.0 release packages. The modern replacement is the [MongoDB Shell (`mongosh`)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/) which is a more fully feastured JavaScript and Node.js REPL environment.

Comment: Thanks for your insights Stennie, I think this is exactly what I wanted to know!

Comment: P.S. I ended up installing the clients package from Ubuntu reps, I always favor officially supported packages (by Ubuntu I mean, it's just easier most of the time) over installing from the internet, I needed it for testing purposes (the shell), 3.6.3 has the SSL and everything. However, I agree that in order to avoid as much issues as possible one should install recent versions of software (especially in production and stuff). And again - great and complete answer, very helpful!

Comment: @Stennie  for step 1, how to find the correct key (`9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4` in your case) for one's own case?

Comment: @Grace As noted in the answer from `abcoep` on this question, the `mongo` shell was deprecated in MongoDB 5.0 a few years after this answer was posted and now has a separate installer: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/.

Comment: This answer could be greatly improved by making it self-contained. How to install `mongosh`?

Comment: @BłażejMichalik I changed the MongoDB Shell link to the [`mongosh` install procedures](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/install/#procedure), but since the install steps and dependencies can vary by Ubuntu release I think there isn't much value in duplicating those here. When this question was originally asked 5 years ago, it was more difficult to find mention of standalone packages for the legacy `mongo` shell in the docs.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to [install](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/install/) `mongosh` (MongoDB Shell) instead. The legacy `mongo` shell has been [deprecated](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongodb-binary-bin.mongo) since MongoDB v5.0 and replaced by `mongosh`. From the [official website](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/#the-mdb-shell-versus-the-legacy-mongo-shell):

> The new MongoDB Shell, `mongosh`, offers numerous advantages over the
> legacy mongo shell, such as:
>
> - Improved syntax highlighting.
> - Improved command history.
> - Improved logging.
>
> Currently mongosh supports a subset of the mongo shell
> methods. Achieving feature parity between mongosh and the mongo shell
> is an ongoing effort.
>
> To maintain backwards compatibility, the methods that mongosh supports
> use the same syntax as the corresponding methods in the mongo shell.
> To see the complete list of methods supported by mongosh, see [MongoDB
> Shell Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/reference/methods/).

Further reference: [Compatibility Changes with Legacy mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/reference/compatibility/)